# app not installed error on android in kotlin gradle 3.0.0-alpha5

Tags: android

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "//"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

and project level

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2-4'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha5'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

actually before i'm using 2.3 gradle at that time there is no error now i changed to 3.0.0-alphs-5 app not installing error.  i do appreciate if u solve this error . is it  kotlin error or anything different i cant find the solution pls help me(this is happening only  while i'm sharing  not by debugging through studio)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
./gradlew --stop
```

and then go to

```
File > invalidate caches / restart > invalidate and restart
```

Comment: Sorry! not helpful

Answer (score 0):

check your manifest if your MainActivity is duplicated.

Comment: Everything is fine